# Computer turns off, but won't turn on

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot

I have a computer that I recieved from somebody but the hard disk said that it wasn't found. I opened it up, and removed the sata connected from the motherboard, and plugged it into another sata port (it looks different, but it's still a sata port) I turned the computer on, and it magically worked again. My guess was that the port was broken. I reinstalled Windows 7 on it, and I haven't had a chance to play with it, but it turns off after a while and the power button then blinks from blue to orange. I move the mouse and touch the keyboard and hit the power button but it won't turn on. I have to unplug it, wait like 20 seconds (for the power button to stop blinking) and then I can plug it back in. I get a windows error recovery screen when it boots back up. I don't get what the problem can be. What steps can I take to troubleshoot? When I get back to the desktop I don't get any messages. Ideas?

Note: The option "Computer Goes to sleep" is set to `never`.

Comment: The power LED changing colors probably indicates sleep mode. I know you've disabled sleep mode, but are you sure the computer isn't sleeping or hibernating? My friend had an issue where his Windows 7 computer couldn't wake from sleep unless "hybrid sleep" was disabled in power settings.

Comment: does it turn back on if you press the power button quickly?  also desktop or laptop

Comment: Okay, so @Huskehn had the answer. I disabled hybrid sleep and it worked perfectly. Also, Kendrick just as a note... this was a desktop.

Comment: can you change the data travel cable once or can you check another hard disk on this sata port and then please tell what happens

Comment: As of right now I don't have an extra sata cable, no extra HDD, and the other sata port doesn't work. Hahaha. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to disable "Hybrid Sleep" under the power settings right off the bat.  If that doesn't do it, try to disable hibernation.

EDIT:
I just realized this was answered in the comments section.